What are the task bar jump lists line spacing registry keys or Classic Shell settings?
My task bar jump lists were single spaced in win 7 but after upgrade to W10 a couple of years ago the lines became wider spaced then even wider spaced 'on their own'.
I'm not sure if this is a Classic shell setting or a windows one. I have classic shell start menu installed.
The left click list is wider spaced than the right-click list so there must be 2 keys/settings.
The actual Classic Shell Start Menu is how I want the lists to look.


Have you rebooted since the problem started to happen? It may just be a bug in memory (turning off and on is not the same as reboot and would not fix the issue as it would persist past a hibernation cycle)

This has been a problem since I installed windows 10 a few years ago. It just got worse, it is persistent.

You could uninstall classic shell, reboot, see if its gone and install Classic shell again. Then you know where it comes from. If it is indeed classic shell, you can do a bug report, see if there's an update that fixes it, or use an alternative (they exist).
